# Disable color and paging for mercurial

Tags: mercurial

New versions of mercurial will apply colors to the output of most commands and will pipe commands with long output to a pager. How do I restore the old behavior to not color output and never use a pager?

Comment: Thanks for your Q&A. Ran into the same thing, although I am not bothered by color. But the uncalled pagination reminded me of a very patronizing DVCS.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Add the following to your .hgrc:

```
[ui]
color = never
paginate = never
```

Answer (score 6):

When working with commandline, you can also add parameters or options to your commands. This is however not permanent. The `hg --help --verbose`  reveals:

```
--color TYPE        when to colorize (boolean, always, auto, never, or debug)
--pager TYPE        when to paginate (boolean, always, auto, or never)
                    (default: auto)
```

So the next command disables your pager and does not show any colors:

```
hg incoming --pager never --color never
```